How to make react-draft-wysiwyg dropdowns work in Next.js App Router?
I'm trying to integrate react-draft-wysiwyg rich text editor into my next.js project, but I'm having problems with the dropdowns for font, font size, and block type. I don't know what the problem is or how to fix this in next.js. There's only so much information online that can help me figure this out. Here's the code:


'use client';
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { EditorState, convertFromRaw, convertToRaw } from 'draft-js';
import { firestore } from '../../firebase';
import { getDoc, doc, updateDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import 'react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css';

const Editor = dynamic(() => import('react-draft-wysiwyg').then(mod => mod.Editor), {
  ssr: false
});

interface Document {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  content: string;
  createdAt: Date;
}

const DocumentPage: React.FC = () => {
  const params = useSearchParams();
  const id = params.get("id");
  const [document, setDocument] = useState<Document | null>(null);
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(() => EditorState.createEmpty());
  const isMounted = useRef(true); // Track mounted state

  useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;
    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDocument = async () => {
      if (id) {
        try {
          const docRef = await getDoc(doc(firestore, `documents/${id}`));
          if (docRef.exists()) {
            const docData = docRef.data() as Document;
            if (isMounted.current) {
              setDocument(docData);

              if (docData.content) {
                try {
                  const contentState = convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(docData.content));
                  const initialEditorState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);
                  setEditorState(initialEditorState);
                } catch (error) {
                  console.error('Error parsing content:', error);
                }
              } else {
                console.warn('Document content is empty or undefined');
              }
            }
          } else {
            console.error('Document not found');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching document: ', error);
        }
      }
    };

    fetchDocument();
  }, [id]);

  const handleEditorChange = (newEditorState: EditorState) => {
    setEditorState(newEditorState);
  };

  const saveDocument = async () => {
    if (!document || !editorState) return;

    try {
      const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
      const rawContentState = convertToRaw(contentState);

      await updateDoc(doc(firestore, `documents/${id}`), {
        content: JSON.stringify(rawContentState)
      });

      console.log('Document saved successfully');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error saving document: ', error);
    }
  };

  if (!document) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{document.title}</h1>
      <Editor
        editorState={editorState}
        onEditorStateChange={handleEditorChange}
        placeholder="Start typing..."
        toolbar={{
          options: ['inline', 'blockType', 'fontSize', 'fontFamily', 'list', 'textAlign', 'colorPicker', 'link', 'embedded', 'emoji', 'image', 'remove', 'history'],
          inline: { options: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'monospace'], inDropdown: false },
          blockType: {inDropdown: true, options: ['Normal', 'header-one', 'header-two', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5', 'H6', 'Blockquote', 'Code'] },
          fontSize: {inDropdown: true, options: [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18, 24, 30, 36, 48, 60, 72, 96] },
          fontFamily: {inDropdown: true, options: ['Arial', 'Georgia', 'Impact', 'Tahoma', 'Times New Roman', 'Verdana'] },
          list: { inDropdown: false },
          textAlign: { inDropdown: false },
          link: { inDropdown: false },
          history: { inDropdown: false }
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={saveDocument}>Save Document</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DocumentPage;



I'm working with the app router.

Hi, it's given that there'll be a problem integrating draft.js with a newer framework because draft js has been deprecated since 2022. Without official support, there'll bound to be bugs that won't be fixed, there's a new library to replace it called lexical that's also maintained by facebook. You can check it out.
